# Efficient comparison between two POJOs to determine the extent of how similar they are

Tags: java

I need to make a comparison between 2 POJOs, but instead of checking for equality, I'm trying to determine how similar they are even though I know they are not the same. For instance, out of the 20 fields they have, I need to determine how many are the same/different.

ex:

```
public class Objekt {
   private int field1;
   private String field2;
   private String field3;
   ...
   private List<Integer> field4;

   public Objekt () {
      ...
   }

   public compareWith (Objekt other) {
      if (field1 != other.field2)
         System.out.println("Field 1 is different");
      if (!field2.equals(other.field2))
         System.out.println("Field 2 is different");
      ...
      // etc
   }
}
```

Having to compare each field manually seems like a lot of extra boilerplate code, and it's also not scalable if I were to need a method similar to this with other object. I was curious if there's a solution out there to do something similar, or if anyone has any ideas on how I could make this more efficient?

New to StackOverflow, thanks for any suggestions! :)

Comment: Could you give us some more information about the purpose of the comparison? Do you only want to compare objects of the same type? Do you only need human readable output - like your example suggests - or should the implementation return a result like some kind of score (e.g. `1.0` represents full equality and `0.0` none at all) or do you want to compare your objects in order to sort them in sortable collections?

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is: Java isn't built for "unstructured" code like you have in mind.

Meaning: there is reflection (see https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/javareflection-1536171.html) for example that allows you to write code that inspects the fields of objects arbitrary classes. But that is extremely cumbersome and error prone, and of course: coming at high performance penalties at runtime.

There are libraries build around that though, like the https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.5/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/EqualsBuilder.html that make things a bit easier to use.

But as said: the real answer is that you normally strive to avoid such designs. You should rather step back and find ways to solve the underlying problem that have better solutions in Java. Or ask yourself why you want to use a statically typed language like Java for a problem that dynamic languages are much better suited for.